# java как разбирать массив объектов и вывести значение на ListView?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, gson

ИСПРАВЛЕНО!
Всех приветствую, у меня есть Json файл находится в директории Assets в нем список всех стран и коды, столицы, и.т.п.. )) выглядеть следующим образом,

```
[
    {
      "Name": "Bangladesh",
      "Unicode": "",
      "Dial": "880"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Belgium",
      "Unicode": "",
      "Dial": "32"
    }
]
```

теперь вопрос: как мне передавать json file находящийся в директории assets в класс и вызвать его в адаптер?

Мой класс которые не знаю где и как использовать!

```
import android.os.Parcelable;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ParseCountry implements Parcelable{

    @SerializedName("Name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("Unicode")
    @Expose
    private String unicode;
    @SerializedName("Dial")
    @Expose
    private String dial;

    public final static Creator<ParseCountry> CREATOR = new Creator<ParseCountry>() {

        @SuppressWarnings({
                "unchecked"
        })
        public ParseCountry createFromParcel(android.os.Parcel in) {
            return new ParseCountry(in);
        }

        public ParseCountry[] newArray(int size) {
            return (new ParseCountry[size]);
        }

    };

    protected ParseCountry(android.os.Parcel in) {
        this.name = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.unicode = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.dial = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
    }

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public ParseCountry() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * @param unicode
     * @param dial
     */
    public ParseCountry(String name, String unicode, String dial) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.unicode = unicode;
        this.dial = dial;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getUnicode() {
        return unicode;
    }

    public String getDial() {
        return dial;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setUnicode(String unicode) {
        this.unicode = unicode;
    }

    public void setDial(String dial) {
        this.dial = dial;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(name);
        dest.writeValue(unicode);
        dest.writeValue(dial);
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

мой адапер

```
// adapter for select country
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,
                // if custom ListView R.layout.custom_list_view, R.id.list_view_id
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_list)); // here for country name !
        selectCountry.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: задачу решил другим способом ссылка на решения
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1352891/3-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-json-%d0%b2-java-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш вопрос: "как мне передавать json file находящийся в директории assets в класс и вызвать его в адаптер?"

1. Написать менеджер (просто класс, который умеет только это делать) для чтения Android Assets.

Пример общего характера: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47201839/5521569

Пример более приближенный к Вашему вопросу: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56994948/5521569

Метод этого менеджера должен возвращать List, где Country - data class, который хранится в себе один объект Вашего массива из файла *.json.

2. Далее этот List нужно передать в Ваш RecyclerViewAdapter. Будет он наследником RecyclerView.Adapter или ListAdapter - выбор за Вами.
3. Лучше использовать в проектах RecyclerView, а не устаревший давным-давно ListView .

Если я правильно понял вторую часть Вашего вопроса, то вот пара примеров:

1. https://medium.com/@hrithik481/implement-recyclerview-in-android-with-kotlin-42408c6bf6
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afl_i6uvvU0
3. https://www.raywenderlich.com/1560485-android-recyclerview-tutorial-with-kotlin