# 3 вопроса по работе с json в java, как решить данную задачу?

Tags: java, android, json

У меня несколько трудностей, которые я не смог решить самостоятельно, обо всем по порядку.

Есть json file, который я показываю в `ListView`, и он выглядит следующим образом:

- `countryData.json`

```
{
  "CountryData": [
    {
      "Name": "Bangladesh",
      "Unicode": "",
      "Dial": "880"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Belgium",
      "Unicode": "",
      "Dial": "32"
    }...
  ]
}
```

- java code

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
JSONObject jsonObject;
JSONArray jsonArray;
String jsonFile;
String unicode;
String name;
String dial;

try {

    InputStream stream = getAssets().open("json/countryData.json");
    int size = stream.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    stream.read(buffer);
    stream.close();
    jsonFile = new String(buffer);

    jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonFile);
    jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("CountryData");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        unicode = jsonObject.getString("Unicode");
        name = jsonObject.getString("Name");
        dial = jsonObject.getString("Dial");

        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("Unicode", unicode);
        hashMap.put("Name", name);
        hashMap.put("Dial", "+"+dial);

        arrayList.add(hashMap);
    }
} catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "json file is not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

- адаптер, который передает данные в `ListView`

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    LoginActivity.this, arrayList, R.layout.simple_layout,
    new String[] {"Unicode", "Name", "Dial"},
    new int[] {R.id.countryUnicode,R.id.countryName, R.id.countryCodeList}
);
selectCountry.setAdapter(adapter);
```

- результат

[image: результат]

Код работает, но не совсем корректно.

**Вернемся к вопросам.**

1. Список стран в ListView выходит по порядку, как написано в Json файле, как сделать, чтобы показывал по алфавиту от А до Я?
2. Когда я выбираю из списка какую-нибудь страну, в `Editext` (TextInputLayout) возвращается весь объект `{Unicode=, Dial=+7, Name=Russia}`
   Как вывести только название выбранной страны?
3. Как получить страну автоматически в поле `Выбор страны`, когда пользователь вводит код страны в поле `Код страны` и наоборот?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Любая помощь приветствуется.

Comment: я думаю, вам стоит сфокусироваться на проблеме и убрать всю шелуху. Напимер, ваши вопросы про отображение уже загруженных данных, потому наверное нет необходимости рассказывать, откуда и как они были загружены.

Comment: ну и вы задаете 3 вопроса в одном. Если вопросы подразумевают разные ответы, то и задавайте из отдельно. Иначе вы просите, чтобы отвечающий писал 3 ответа, а получил балов как за 1 ответ.

Comment: больше информаии о том, как задавать вопросы, вы найдете тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)